# checkbox is not working/uneditable in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, apache-poi, jcheckbox

This class is to create jtable with 6 columns, the last one containing boolean checkboxes. I specified it in getColumnClass. I can't uncheck/check these boxes, they are uneditable. I'm suspecting that methods setValueAt and getValueAt in class MyTableModel aren't correct, but can't get my head around it. Please help. Here are 3 classes I'm showing you: the gui class with main method, the MyTableModel which extends AbstractTableModel and the cell renderer class ColorRenderer.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;

public class table extends JFrame {

    JTable table = new JTable();
    MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel(getDummyData());
    JScrollPane scroll;
    List<Integer> highlightedCell;

    public table() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public Vector getDummyData() throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        highlightedCell = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String nnnname;
        Vector vector;
        Vector vectorOfVector = new Vector();
        excelToList e = new excelToList("input.xls");
        List<Person> names = e.createWorkbook();
        int rowNum = 0;
        for (Person p : names) {
            nnnname = p.getName();
            vector = new Vector();
            vector.add(nnnname);
            vector.add(p.getDone());
            vector.add(p.getWaiting());
            vector.add(p.getORDERED());
            vector.add(p.getKPR1());
            vector.add(new Boolean(false));
            vectorOfVector.add(vector);
            rowNum++;
            if ((nnnname.matches("\\A\\p{ASCII}*\\z"))) {
                highlightedCell.add(rowNum - 1);
            }
        }
        return vectorOfVector;

    }

    public void createTable() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InvalidFormatException {


        table.setModel(model);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        TableCellRenderer original = table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class,
                new ColorRenderer(highlightedCell, original));
        scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scroll);
        setSize(1000, 1000);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,     InvalidFormatException {
        table t = new table();
        t.createTable();
    }
}

class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] columnName = {"NAME", "DONE", "WAITING",
        "OVERALL", "PERCENTAGE 1", "PERCENTAGE 2"};
    private Vector dataVector;

    public MyTableModel(Vector vectorOfVector) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        dataVector = vectorOfVector;

    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return dataVector.size();
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnName.length;
    }
    Vector v;

    public Object getValueAt(int i, int i1) {
        v = (Vector) dataVector.elementAt(i);
        return v.elementAt(i1);
    }

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        switch (c) {
            case 5:
                return Boolean.class;
            default:
                return String.class;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        if (col < 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        Vector rowVector = (Vector) dataVector.get(row);
        rowVector.set(col, value);

        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }
}


class ColorRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

    List<Integer> highlightedCoordinates;
    private TableCellRenderer cellRenderer;

    public ColorRenderer(List<Integer> list, TableCellRenderer cellRenderer) {
        if (cellRenderer == this || cellRenderer == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.cellRenderer = cellRenderer;

        highlightedCoordinates = list;

    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jtable, Object color,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component c;
        c = cellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(jtable, color, hasFocus, hasFocus, row, row);


        if (column == 0 && highlightedCoordinates.contains(row)) {
            c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        } else {
            c.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        }

        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to return `true` from `isCellEditable` for `col = 5`? If that does not work, then try to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), it's impossible to compile your code.

Comment: You should seriously consider following Java coding conventions as your code is really hard to read for other programmers. Also consider typing your Vector's and use meaningful variable names. ONe last thing, instead of writing `if (col < 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
` simply write: `return col<1;`. It is like writing `if(true) return true else return false;`

Comment: I normally clean up when I finish. sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
    if (col < 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If my understanding is correct you are trying to set only the 0th col as editable. Add the col index of checkbox to return as true.

Answer (score 1):

change your `isCellEditable(int row, int col)` as anthoon said to the following:

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {   
  if (col < 1) {    
      return true;  
  } else if( col == 5){//column with your checkboxes.
      return true;
  } else {
      return false;   
  }
}
```